# Trying to pass CGrect to performSelector withObject

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, selector, argument-passing

I'm trying to pass a CGRect:

```
SEL frameSel = NSSelectorFromString(@"setFrame:");
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100);
[object performSelector:frameSel withObject:rect ];
```

But this does not compile

I also tried:

```
SEL frameSel = NSSelectorFromString(@"setFrame:");
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100);
NSValue * value = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
[object performSelector:frameSel withObject:value ];
```

Actually, this does compile but when I debug, the frame is not setted correctly:

```
po object
<UILabel: 0x39220f0; frame = (0 0; 200 100); text = 'reflectionLabel'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x3922240>>
```

But it should be frame = (10 10; 200 100)

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100);
> [object performSelector:frameSel withObject:rect ];
> ```
>
> But this does not compile

Correct, because `rect` is a structure, not a pointer to an object.

> ```
> CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100);
> NSValue * value = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
> [object performSelector:frameSel withObject:value ];
> ```
>
> Actually, this does compile but when I debug, the frame is not setted correctly:
>
> ```
> po object
> <UILabel: 0x39220f0; frame = (0 0; 200 100); text = 'reflectionLabel'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x3922240>>
> ```

Well, it's not garbage, so it would seem that it worked, even though the origin somehow remained zero. You may want to ask a separate question about that.

Anyway, why are you using `performSelector:withObject:`? You're not addressing it to a specific thread and you're not putting it on a delay; why not simply say `object.frame = rect`?

Comment: Object is of type NSObject *

I cannot simply say object.frame
I really need to use NSObject*



>>> Well, it's not garbage, so it would seem that it worked, even though the origin somehow remained zero. You may want to ask a separate question about that.

I really need an answer on that question.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you know it has a `frame` property, cast it to `UIView *` and then use `object.frame = rect`. If you don't know it has a `frame` property, use KVC (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/) to set the property, and catch the exception that will happen if it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 5):

You must use an NSInvocation to handle any non-id arguments or return values:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(104, 300, 105, 106);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

NSMethodSignature *methodSig = [view methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setFrame:)];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSig];
invocation.target = view;
invocation.selector = @selector(setFrame:);
[invocation setArgument:&rect atIndex:2];
[invocation invoke];
```