# Send CGRect to performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, performselector

I am trying to run a method that takes a `CGRect` parameter after 2 seconds with the following line of code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(drawLineChart:) withObject:rect afterDelay:2.0];
```

but I get the error:

> Sending 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'

How can I work around this?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302415/trying-to-pass-cgrect-to-performselector-withobject?s=1|1.9200

Comment: Better yet, use `dispatch_after` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.